# Jest: moduleNameMapper is not working for one path

Tags: reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

Cannot find module 'illustrations/index' from 'src/components/ErrorPage/index.tsx'
`import { ServerErrorSvg } from 'illustrations/index';`

This works if i change it to
`import { ServerErrorSvg } from 'images/illustrations/index';`

This import is working fine in the project. I tried pathsToModuleNameMapper of ts-jest. That is not working.

Jest config

```
module.exports = { rootDir: 'src',
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
  moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'tsx', 'js', 'jsx', 'json'],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.(j|t)sx?$': 'babel-jest',
    '^.+\\.svg$': '<rootDir>/svgTransform.js'
  },
  moduleDirectories: ['node_modules', 'src', 'src/images', './src/images'],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '\\.(css|less|scss|sass|jpg|jpeg|png)$': 'identity-obj-proxy',
    'single-spa-react/parcel': 'single-spa-react/lib/cjs/parcel.cjs',
    '^images/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/images/$1',
    '^illustrations/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/../src/images/illustrations'
  },
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/src/setupTests.js']
}
```

tsconfig

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "lib/esm",
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["es6", "dom", "es2016", "es2017"],
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "declaration": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "types/*": ["types/*"],
      "types": ["types/"],
      "hooks/*": ["hooks/*"],
      "hooks": ["hooks/index"],
      "components/*": ["components/*"],
      "icons/*": ["images/icons/*"],
      "illustrations/*": ["images/illustrations/*"],
      "@mui/styled-engine": ["./node_modules/@mui/styled-engine-sc"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["src", "src/custom.d.ts"],
  "exclude": [
    "lib",
    "node_modules",
    "**/*.DS_Store",
    "src/**/*.spec.ts",
    "src/**/*.spec.tsx",
    "src/**/*.test.ts",
    "src/**/*.test.tsx",
    "src/**/*.stories.ts",
    "src/**/*.stories.tsx",
    "**/__test__"
  ]
}
```

Tried adding this to moduleNameMapper

```
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '\\.(css|less|scss|sass|jpg|jpeg|png)$': 'identity-obj-proxy',
    'single-spa-react/parcel': 'single-spa-react/lib/cjs/parcel.cjs',
    '^images/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/images/$1',
    '^illustrations/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/../src/images/illustrations'
  }
```

This absolute import should have been resolved successfully like it does for ts